# Get custom headers in response, rest-easy

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpresponse, resteasy

**Server**

```
Class MyService{

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse httpResponse;

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public String handlePostRequest(Object resource) {

    httpResponse.addHeader("X-Origin", resPrim.getFrom());
    httpResponse.addHeader("X-RI", resPrim.getRequestIdentifier());
    httpResponse.addHeader("X-RET", resPrim.getResultExpirationTimestamp());
    httpResponse.setStatus(getHttpStatusCode());

    return "DUMMY"; 

}
```

**Client:**

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpUriRequest);

System.out.println("RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    for (Header h: httpResponse.getAllHeaders()) {           
                    //Do your stuff here
                    System.out.println("HEADER" + h); 
    }
```

When I get my headers printed on the client side, SOP shows:

```
HEADER Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
HEADER Content-Type: application/json
HEADER Content-Length: 4
HEADER Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 08:33:53 GMT
```

Are my response headers not getting added ??

I want to get the custom headers I had set at server printed, but the response has only the 4 headers as above.

How to obtain custom headers ??

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure there's no filter or proxy in between which may drop headers? Also I would prefer using [Response.ResponseBuilder#header](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#header(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)). JAX-RS needs to sync the headers with the ServletResponse and for me this did not work always as expected.

Comment: @lefloh: The issue was solved as my headers were not populated with any content, thus they were not showing in SOP